# Get height of content items

Tags: wpf, height, actualheight

Cannot determine Height or ActualHeight of the following:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="statusCounter"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Loading " x:Name="txtLoading" />
        <!-- more TextBlock's -->
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

`txtLoading` gives a height of ~12
`statusCounter` the Border has an ActualHeight of 2.

The desired result should be 24 for statusCounter:

- `txtLoading` is 12
- `Border` is 2
- `Margin` is 10 (5 times 2 for the top and bottom)

The above Border control is placed in a Grid that is to be animated to disappear when another control finishes loading.

Should I be wrapping the above in a different container to get the actual height of the whole?

Comment: Your example does not use an element with the name "self", are you referring to the [`RelativeSource Self`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx)?

Comment: @Dom self is the name of the top control `UserControl` since the name `this` is taken.

Comment: what is the value that you are getting for ActualHeight of statusCounter?

Comment: Try set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` (it does not matter what kind of alignment) for `StackPanel`.

Comment: @nit ActualHeight for statusCounter is `2`

Answer (score 0):

`ElementName=self` reference to what if this view has a viewModel you can set as this 
`Text="{Binding Items.Count}"`
you can use Canvas instead of grid

Comment: Kobe, I don't get what you are saying here.